# Is there a way to use NgbDatepicker's navigateTo() on the component other than using it on ngAfterViewInit()?

Tags: angular, datepicker, ngb-datepicker

I am using the `NgbDatepicker`

```
<ngb-datepicker #dp [(ngModel)]="scheduledStartDate" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}">
</ngb-datepicker>
```

It can be done on `ngAfterViewInit()` like:

```
@ViewChild('dp') datepicker: NgbDatepicker;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.datepicker.navigateTo({ year: new Date().getFullYear(), month: new Date().getMonth(), day: new Date().getDate() });
}
```

But is there a way to use `navigateTo()` on some other function ??

Comment: You can use it programmatically once you're sure the view has been initialised...what do you want to do ?

Comment: I want the Datepicker to open a particular month. How can it be used programmatically? @WillAlexander

Comment: Once the view is initalised (hence why you're using it in `ngAfterViewInit`), you can call the DatePicker's `navigateTo` method from anywhere.

Comment: No, it gives an error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigateTo' of undefined`

Comment: That means the view was not initialised, that’s my point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `NgbDatepicker` until it is initialised. To be sure that it is available, we have `ngAfterViewInit` hook. So if you want to do some initialisation, you can do it in `ngAfterViewInit`. But if you still want to use it from some function which is called before `view initialisation` (let's say constructor since you did not show us where you're calling it from), you can use `setTimeout` as a workaround but I don't recommend doing that. See below component for instance -

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('dp') datepicker: NgbDatepicker;
  scheduledStartDate: NgbDateStruct = {year: 2222, month: 10, day: 10};
constructor(private calendar: NgbCalendar) {
  console.log(this.datepicker? 'NgDatePicker is available': 'NgDatePicker not initialized');
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.datepicker.navigateTo({year:2090, month: 10});
  }, 1000);
}
ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.datepicker? 'NgDatePicker is available': 'NgDatePicker not initialized');
}
}
```

Please check [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngb-datepicker-popup-jumping-dhwh1h?file=app/app.component.ts) example which works just fine. The `app.component.html` has two buttons to navigate to two different years.

**Update**:

You can also use `startDate` in your `<ngb-datepicker>` -

```
<div *ngIf="addEditForm">
    <ngb-datepicker #dp [(ngModel)]="scheduledStartDate"  [startDate]="scheduledStartDate" (navigate)="date = $event.next" *ngIf="addEditForm"></ngb-datepicker>
 </div>
```

And then keep changing `scheduledStartDate` instead of using `this.datepicker.navigateTo({})`

```
openAddForm() {
    this.addEditForm = true;
    this.scheduledStartDate = {year: 5555, month: 10, day: 10};
  }
```

Refer to [this api document](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api) to know more.

Comment: In my case, on the function in which I'm using the navigateTo button opens the form. I have tweaked your stackblitz a little to fit to my example. https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngb-datepicker-popup-jumping-cfcgyt and you can see the error there.

Comment: @Neha See the `openAddForm()` in https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngb-datepicker-popup-jumping-fqfsiy?file=app/app.component.ts. It takes some time for the element to be available in the `dom` before you can use it.

Comment: The `navigateTo ` still gives an error, but the `[startDate]` this worked for me. Thanks @Akash

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set any specific date then :

`<ngb-datepicker #dp [(ngModel)]="model" (navigate)="date = $event.next"></ngb-datepicker>`

and using button events :

`<button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary mr-2" (click)="dp.navigateTo()">To current month</button>`

`<button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary mr-2" (click)="dp.navigateTo({year: 2021, month: 2})">To Feb 2021</button>`

and In component -

`import {NgbDateStruct, NgbCalendar} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';`
 `export class NgbdDatepickerBasic {`

`model: NgbDateStruct;`
`date: {year: number, month: number};`

`constructor(private calendar: NgbCalendar) {}`

`selectToday() {this.model = this.calendar.getToday();}`
`}`

Refer to https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-basic.ts

without ngAfterViewInit()